# WordPress 3.4 Permalinks Redirection Problem

Tags: permalinks, urls, redirect

A few years ago this was the permalink structure I had for my blog:

> /%year%/%category%/%postname%.html

I changed these permalinks last year to this:

> /%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/

A plugin that goes by the name Permalinks Redirect was used, and it worked pretty well to permanently redirect older URLs to newer ones. However, after a recent WordPress update to 3.4.1 version, I noticed the older permalinks are no longer redirecting.

The problem is not with the plugin -- I have spent 2 days dabbling with every redirect plugin I could find. After a bit of Googling, I figured out the problem is with WordPress 3.4, and [a bug has been already submitted](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-permalinks-not-redirect-the-old-to-the-new#post-2913004).

All the older URLs are throwing out 404 errors, which is frustrating. I'd really appreciate if there's a HTACCESS redirect code, or MOD_REWRITE code (the site is using nginx, if that helps) that could be posted here.

I have very little knowledge about redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but not 100% sure it will work since the post_id is not in the original permalink structure.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ http://domain.com/$2/$3/`

Comment: Chris, thanks a lot! The code almost works -- yes, there is no post_ID in the original permalink, and the URLs do not redirect properly. I tweaked the code a bit: 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ http://domain.com/?p=$1

This redirects to another random post, although this is not what I need. Adding (\d+) to the HTML structure solves the problem, but our older permalink structure doesn't have post_ID as you have already mentioned. What do you think is the best solution? How can we inject post_ID in these URLs?

Answer (score -1):

First of all how are you possibly using mod_rewrite rules in an nginx powered site? That's a neat trick I'd like to learn :)

Anyway if you are using Apache try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ example.com/?name=$3
```

The above uses the post's slug instead of the ID (which is missing in the old URLs). WP should redirect again to your SE friendly URLs.